# How do I use redirect_to() with everything in the current params[] array in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to send the redirect_to function all of the current page's parameters without knowing the individual params. The parameters on a particular page are variable in quantity and are not always known during development. So far I have only found examples of sending known params and values.

I **want** to do this:

```
redirect_to named_path, :notice => 'Some notice.', :params => params
```

I **don't want** to do this:

```
redirect_to named_path, :notice => 'Some notice.', :param1 => "v1", :param2 => "v2", ...
```

TIA!

Comment: Where you ever able to solve this? I have a situation where I'm saving the params hash in the db, but I have no named path to follow when I send it back to `redirect_to`...

Answer (score 2):

This could work: (not tested it)

```
redirect_to named_path, params.merge({ :notice => 'Some notice' })
```

The idea is to make the last parameter of `redirect_to` a *single* hash based on the original `params` hash and merge in any additional value.

Comment: Ah phooey, It doesn't work! That totally looks reasonable to me though. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> redirect_to named_path(params.merge(:notice => 'Some notice.'))

you can even change parameters, delete some by using params.merge() with his normal behavior :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add more params to current path with:

```
redirect_to request.params.merge({new_params: 'foo'})
```

Further, you can pass all of the current params with a new param to a new path with this code:

```
redirect_to new_path(request.params.merge({new_params: 'foo'}).except(:action, :controller))
```

`params` is an instance of `ActionController::Parameters`. So it can't be converted to hash and doesn't support `.merge` method. Thus, use `request.params` instead.